# Convert select items while unpacking a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of strings. I want to unpack it to individual variables, and while doing this I want to convert some of the strings to ints.

The brute force method might look like this

```
>>> my_list = ['a', '1', '2']
>>> a, b, c = my_list
>>> b = int(b)
>>> c = int(c)
>>> a,b,c
('a', 1, 2)
```

I'm looking for a way to do the conversions as part of the original assignment, so that I end up with something like:

```
>>> a, b, c = < some magic here >
>>> a,b,c
('a', 1, 2)
```

Anyone know what magic I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your `my_list` either up stream or now before unpacking:

```
my_list = ['a', '1', '2']

a,b,c = (int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in my_list )
print(type(a), type(b), type(c)) 
# <str, int int>
```

Comment: Final code looks like:

    `for mac, t, l, v in [(mac, int(t), int(l), v) for mac, t, l, v in responses]:`

Answer (score 1):

How about having a custom function and using map

```
def conInt(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
my_list = ['a', '1', '2']
a, b, c = map(conInt, my_list)
print a,b,c
```

**Result:**

```
a 1 2
```